# Propriedade de uma classe que pertence a outro contexto no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma classe chamada Locker que tem a seguinte propriedade :

```
public virtual ICollection<LockerReserve> Reserves { get; set; }
```

O problema é que LockerReserve pertence a um contexto diferente de Locker. É lançada uma exceção sempre quando tento recuperar um locker , pois ele não consegue obter a lista de LockerReserve.

```
public Locker GetLockerById(int lockerId)
{
    var lockers = _lockerContext.Lockers
        .Where(b => b.LockerId == lockerId);

    return lockers.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

É possível uma classe ter uma lista de um tipo que não está no seu contexto no Entity Framework ?

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que você quer fazer...  Coloca o código de onde a exceção está sendo lançada, não entendi o que seria recuperar no seu contexto

Comment: Coloquei o método onde a exceção é lançada. Quando ele vai pegar um locker do contexto dá erro, pois Locker tem uma lista de LockerReserve que pertence a um outro contexto. E não posso colocar LockerReserve no mesmo contexto de Locker, pois ele também será acessado em outros contextos.

Comment: E como o objeto Locker está mapeado no banco? Porque ele não inventa que Locker tem um LockerReserve, ou vc mapeou na mão ou ele criou o contexto baseado no banco. Como está isso?

Comment: Fiz o mapeamento pelo código mesmo. Locker tem uma coleção de LockerReserve e LockerReserve tem o Id de um Locker.

Comment: E a propriedade LockerReserve está apontando para qual tabela? Ou não está aponto para nada? Estou fazendo esse monte de perguntas porque a forma de jogar um dentro do outro é fazendo apend, Se no contexto 1 o objeto não existe então não tem como dar apend nele, entende?

Answer (score 1):

> É possível uma classe ter uma lista de um tipo que não está no seu contexto no Entity Framework?

Não. Quase certo de que não funcionará.

A importância de ter todas as entidades mapeadas em apenas um contexto é exatamente a de garantir a coesão entre as entidades. Separando, você não tem como dizer ao contexto que aquela relação existe, portanto, o apontamento da exceção é correto.

Não sei o motivo pelo qual você quer esta separação, mas há maneiras melhores de resolver o problema. Só preciso de mais detalhamento na sua pergunta para melhorar esta resposta (qual o motivo da separação, quais são os aspectos desta implementação que precisam ser considerados, entre outros).